# B-Splines Matlab Package

Tags: matlab, approximation, b-spline

I'm looking for a good Matlab package/library for B-Splines approximation. Ideally, it would take knots $t_1, \ldots , t_n$, and data points $g(t_1),\ldots , g(t_n)$, and Produce $$Vg :\,= \sum\limits_{j=1}^n B_i ^k (t) g_i \, , $$ 
where the $B_i ^k$'s are the B-spline basis of order $k$ with respect to the given knots-set.

*Remarks:*

- Really, I just need the cubic B-Splines, and "simple" knots, i.e., without repeating a note twice.
- I follow the definitions in pp. 160 of C. De Boor, A Practical Guide to Splines, 1978.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use Curve fitting toolbox which is provided by MATLAB.
The function you need is `spcol`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not entirely sure how to use `spcol` in this context. The example in the documentation is very much in an ODE prespective, which is not familiar to me. Do you know of any simple example ?

Comment: If you just want to create B-Splines, [nurbs toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26390-nurbs-toolbox-by-d-m-spink) could be a better choice.